# Figures appear after their text in latex

Tags: graphics, floats, hyperref, captions

When I click on the reference of the figure on the article its caption appears directly instead of all the figure then I have to go up to see the figure.
I used it:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,showkeys,prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
and 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8.5cm,keepaspectration=true]{./image}
\caption{image.png}
\label{fig:exp_diag}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually package `caption` or package `hypcap` fixes the issue. A starting point:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,showkeys,prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\caption{image.png}
\label{fig:exp_diag}
\end{figure}

Ref: \ref{fig:exp_diag}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I still have problem:  when, I add the new packages :\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,showkeys,prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}, the figure appear when I click on its reference but the lines of its caption are not aligned successively.  Could one help me, please?

Comment: @user118607 No, I cannot help. TL has about 4000 LaTeX packages. That makes a number of 2^4000 package combinations, a number with *1205* decimal digits. Make a correct and tested [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It would show the problematic packages and maybe someone can help.